# Using a parameterized subtype of a templated type inside of another templated type

Tags: c++, templates

Is it possible to achieve the following behaviour?

```
template<typename T>
struct X {
    template<const bool Condition>
    struct Y;

    template<>
    struct Y<true> {
        typedef T Z;
    };
};


template<typename T>
struct A {
    typedef typename T::Y<true>::Z B;  // Error
};


int main() {
    X<float>::Y<true>::Z value = 5.0f;  // OK

    A<X<float>>::B value2 = 5.0f;  // Desired behaviour

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [Not ok for me](http://liveworkspace.org/code/rIPFY$2)

Comment: Interesting. Using MSVC 2012 (Platform toolset 120)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
typedef typename T::template Y<true>::Z B;
```

It works in gcc 4.7.2

Though gcc complains about full specialization inside a struct, so I had to add a dummy parameter.